# High-traffic, low disk utilization AWS solution

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, traffic

I've got a high-traffic (imagine tracking server) node.js server that's going to run on AWS EC2. There is no disk operation involved, but a lot of DynamoDB requests (in same zone), ElastiCache usage and as I said - a lot of network I/O (small packets, < 0.5kB, about 5-10 per second).

What would be best solution for this situation? A few smaller-scale servers like m1.medium or m1.large in a load-balancer, or a single m1.xlarge server? Main problem with xlarge I have is that it offers *a lot* of storage which I absolutely don't need...

Comment: Profile your application on each instance type and decide which one works best for your needs. That is *the only way* to make a good decision about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the AWS [instance type](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) page.
2. Look at the `Network Performance` column.
3. Pick one with `moderate`.
4. Run with it and see if it works out. (or even better, benchmark it!)
5. If it's too slow, upgrade to something with `high`.

Experience tells!